# code causing the IE 8 to change to IE7 compatibilty mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have written a javascript function which will create a pop up ,and i am calling the function from my code.But when ever i click on the button ie changes to ie 7 compatibilty mode and i see my pop up behind the button.

here is my java script :

```
(function(){


jQuery.fn.popbox = function(options){
var settings = jQuery.extend({
selector      : this.selector,
open          : '.open',
box           : '.box',
close         : '.close'
}, options);


var methods = {
open: function(event){
    methods.close();
    jQuery('.collapse').show();
    createpopbox();

event.preventDefault();
//alert("In code");

var pop = jQuery(this);
var box = jQuery(this).parent().find(settings['box']);
//alert(jQuery(this).attr("class"));
var open= jQuery(this).parent().find(settings[jQuery(this).attr("class")]);



if(box.css('display') == 'block'){
methods.close();
} else {
box.css({'display': 'block', 'top': (jQuery(this).position()).top + 12, 'left':(jQuery(this).position()).left  });
}
},

close: function(){
jQuery(settings['box']).hide();//.fadeOut("fast");
removedivs();

}
};


jQuery(document).bind('keyup', function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 27){
methods.close();
}
});


jQuery(document).bind('click', function(event){
if(!jQuery(event.target).closest(settings['selector']).length){
methods.close();
}
});


return this.each(function(){
jQuery(this).css({'width': jQuery(settings['box']).width()}); // Width needs to be set otherwise popbox will not move when window resized.
jQuery(settings['open'], this).bind('click', methods.open);
jQuery(settings['open'], this).parent().find(settings['close']).bind('click', methods.close);
});
};


}).call(this);
    function createpopbox(){
    jQuery('<div class="arrow"></div>'+
'<div class="arrow-border"></div>'
).appendTo('.box');;
    }
    function removedivs(){
    jQuery('form').remove('#subForm');
    jQuery('div').remove('.arrow');
    jQuery('div').remove('.arrow-border');
    }
```

i have tried adding the meta tag to force the page to stay on ie 8 but its not working .

Can anyone help me out of this?

Thanks

Comment: always prepare a `jsfiddle link` for such questions, as this will easily allow to test your scripts or code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the code, browser use compatibility mode by default for intranet sites